# ImportError: cannot import name verify_session

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a simple calculator, but I'm getting `ImportError: cannot import name verify_session`.

I guess it's some kind of circular import but I'm not sure how to fix these kind of errors.

**folder structure**

```
/calculator
/--app.py
/--decorators.py
```

**app.py**

```
from decorators import verify_session


class InvalidAmountException(Exception):
    pass


class InvalidSessionException(Exception):
    pass


class Calculator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.amount = 150
        self.password = 'randompass123'
        self.session = False

    def __check_balance(self, amount):
        if self.amount - amount < 0:
            raise InvalidAmountException
        return True

    def kill(self):
        self.session = False
        return self.session

    @verify_session
    def withdrawal(self, amount):
        try:
            self.__check_balance(amount)
            self.amount -= amount
        except InvalidAmountException:
            print 'Sum amount not avaliable!'

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.amount += amount

    def get_amount(self):
        return self.amount


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = Calculator()
    m.deposit(150)
    m.withdrawal(21)
    m.withdrawal(2451)
```

**decorators.py**

```
from app import InvalidSessionException

def verify_session(func):
    def func_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.session:
            raise InvalidSessionException

    return func_wrapper
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, you are seeing a circular dependency between app.py and decorators.py.

I suggest moving the exceptions out of app.py into their own file, e.g. myExceptions.py and import them in app.py and decorators.py.

**myExceptions.py**

```
class InvalidAmountException(Exception):
    pass

class InvalidSessionException(Exception):
    pass
```

**app.py**

```
from decorators import verify_session

from myExceptions import InvalidAmountException, InvalidSessionException

...
```

**decorators.py**

```
from myExceptions import InvalidSessionException

...
```

Comment: That was my first though, but it still didn't work. In that case i get `ImportError: cannot import name InvalidSessionException` in `decorators.py`

Comment: I'll update my answer with a short example that might clear up, also suggesting a different name for your exceptions file in order to avoid any potential namespace collisions with builtin exception classes.

Comment: you're right. the name was the problem. once i've changed it, everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

@Erik suggestion is working. I have created file myExceptions.py 
and moved the custom exception classes there. Please the check the code below :

```
#myexceptions.py

class InvalidAmountException(Exception):
    pass


class InvalidSessionException(Exception):
    pass

#Modified a code bit in decorators.py

from myexceptions import InvalidSessionException

def verify_session(func):
    def func_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if not self.session:
            raise InvalidSessionException
        except InvalidSessionException:
        print "Invalid session. Logging off..."
    return func_wrapper

#When I executed app.py my output is looking like this...

E:\calc>python app.py
Invalid session. Logging off...
Invalid session. Logging off...

E:\calc>
```